# How to submit multiple input fields through a submit button in mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Normally when you have multiple input fields they are all tied to one id. So map from the View to the database is rather straightforward. However in my situation I have multiple inputs (ex. 2 textboxes on one row and a dropdownlist and textbox on another row) that each have an id. I would like to be able to be able to press a submit button and have all it update properly.

Note: formRow is a ViewModel.

Some sample code:

```
<div class="ctrl">
                &nbsp;
                @{
                    foreach (var rowInput in formRow.RowInput)
                    {  
                        switch (rowInput.RowCtrl.Type)
                        {
                            case "dropdown":
                                ; break;
                            case "text":
                               @Html.TextBoxFor(blah => rowInput.InputtedData) ; break;
                            case "radio":
                                ; break;
                            case "checkbox":
                                ; break;
                        }       
                    }
                }
            </div>
            <div class="done">
                <input id="@formRow.RowInput[0].InputtedDataID" type="button" value="button" />
            </div>
```

Actual HTML Source view:

```
<div class="ctrl">
                &nbsp;
<input id="rowInput_InputtedData" name="rowInput.InputtedData" type="text" value="UP, UP, DOWN, DOWN, LEFT, LEFT, RIGHT, RIGHT, B, A, B, A, START" />            </div>
            <div class="done">
                <input id="2" type="button" value="button" />
            </div>
```

Comment: When you say `and have all it update properly` what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: What are you doing in that code?  Why aren't your elements tied to a meaningful model?

Comment: When I pressed the submit button the inputs will be save to the correct records (ids).

Comment: Are you wrapping all your form markup in a form element? You will need to do this so that all inputs will be treated as a collection when submitting.

Comment: @AndrewCritchley Yes, I am. Html.Beginform is what I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

I get the impression you need to read some MVC3 basics. From what I gather you're simply trying to submit form data for server side handling, and that is very straight forward to do with MVC3. Normally you would have a controller with an action capable of returning some ActionResult, which often happens to be a View, visualizing an underlying Model you have created. In the View you could then use Html.BeginForm() to construct a form based upon this Model.

The submit button would then send a Post to the same controller but then to an action capable of handling a post of the resulting Model.

[This blog post](http://blog.codeville.net/2007/11/20/aspnet-mvc-pipeline-lifecycle/) sums up nicely the most basic parts you need to know:

- From Global.asax, add a Route object representing a certain URL pattern you want to catch and map to a controller / action
- Add a Controller subclass, whose [ControllerActions] should be invoked in response to requests, populating ViewData
- Add a view template that uses ViewData to render some HTML

The rest of the post might or might not be interesting depending upon how technical you want to get.

I would recommend looking at some basic introductions to building MVC3 applications. Try working through this one: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript